# php_redis.dll not working in windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, redis

I tried both the files from here: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/downloads. I am using 64bit wampserver on windows 7 professional. It looks like apache is trying to load the file but somehow could not recognize it properly. This is what I see in the error log:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_redis.dll' - %1 is not a valid
>   Win32 application.

Anyone faced similar issues? Do we have a working solution for this?

Comment: put  the value of `extension_dir` in your `php.ini`. it should be something like `C:\xampp\php\ext`

Comment: @ZiTAL I tried both the DLLs. Do you have a link for working dll?

Comment: i wish this will be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001075/which-php-module-to-use-with-redis

Comment: I am not looking for a php library like predis. I wanted to have the extension working - specially for speed and session.save_path=redis.

Comment: Is the path, `D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_redis.dll`, proper? I wonder whether the forward slashes should be back slashes (\) instead, but if this is in line with how it's laid out in Apache's .conf file then this may be irrelevant.

Comment: Location is not a problem - as apache can find out the file - its just not recognizing it as valid application.

Comment: is [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60195) relative?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it can help someone, I managed to solve the error on PHP 7.1.12 installing the 32 bits DLL.

I was getting the error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '.../php_redis.dll'
not a valid Win32 application
```

But after installing the 32 bits version, the warning disappeared.

To know which architecture of XAMPP/WAMP are you using, visit the phpinfo() and look for the value "Architecture", it was for me on the fourth row, and as expected is had the value *x86*.

Answer (score 5):

I had to check the `Server API` from `phpinfo()` to decide which version to use

If It's
**Apache 2.0 Handler(mod_php)** go with **Thread Safe** version

If It's **CGI** go with **Non Thread Safe** version

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not run 64-bit version of PHP to test this, but for PHP 5.3 you can try [this dll](http://code.google.com/p/pecl-win/downloads/detail?name=php_redis-2.1.3-5.3-ts.dll&can=2&q=).

Dll from https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/downloads ( php_redis-2.1.3-5.2-vc6-ts-4350b2a.zip ), is working fine with PHP 5.2.17 (*32-bit version*).

I hope you will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used XAMPP x86 / PHP `7.2.5` so I needed redis x86 and the directory is this: `C:/xampp/php/ext/`.

https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/4.1.0/windows

Answer (score 0):

I'll  add my ansewer to the table :

I used those dlls for my AMPPS server (WAMP should be the same) under windows 8  with PHP 5.5:
https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/2.2.7/windows

following this tutorial

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-redis-windows-php-shekhar-joshi

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for 64 bit windows 7 wampserver with PHP5.5.12
and worked for me from below link dll binaries of Redis

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/redis/2.2.7/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case, I was installing wamp 32bit, but I imported the library in 64bit however I had to imorted the 32bit version.

Check in the task manager which version of wamp you are using!

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was version of `Redis PHP extension` that I've been used.

- xampp architecture: x64
- php version: 7.4
- php type: ts (thread safe)
- redis version installed on windows: 3.0.504

and finally the version of `Redis PHP extension` that worked for me was:

- for php 7.4
- latest stable version: `php_redis-5.3.4-7.4-ts-vc15-x64`
  I downloaded it from this [Link](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.3.4/windows)

Answer (score 0):

From php info, get your php extension build, then choose accordingly the php_redis package to be downloaded

[image: Php info]